# My popup window isn't opening isn't opening on my movie app

Tags: javascript

Hi guys my app is working pretty well but I don't know why my popup window isn't working. I need to make it dynamically and maybe that is the problem but any help would be appreciated. thanks, guys I could use the help

```js
const resBttn = document.querySelector('.resBttn');
const popupSection = document.querySelector('.popup');
   
const createPopup = (element, details) => {
    const popup = document.createElement('div');
    popup.classList.add('popup');
    const popupTitle = document.createElement('h2');
    popupTitle.classList.add('popupTitle');
    popupTitle.innerHTML = element.show.name;
    popup.append(popupTitle);
    const popupImg = document.createElement('img');
    popupImg.classList.add('popupImg');
    popupImg.src = element.show.image.medium;
    popup.append(popupImg);
    const popupDetails = document.createElement('p');
    popupDetails.classList.add('popupDetails');
    popupDetails.innerHTML = details;
    popup.append(popupDetails);
    const popupClose = document.createElement('button');
    popupClose.classList.add('popupClose');
    popupClose.innerHTML = 'Close';
    popup.append(popupClose);
    document.body.append(popup);
};


resBttn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popupSection.style.display = 'block';
    createPopup();
    renderMovies();
});
```

Here guys is my HTML section but there isn't much here

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <img id="logo-img" src="tv.svg" alt="logo">
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul id="nav-list"><li><a href="#">Movies</a></li><li><a href="#">TV Shows</a></li>li><a href="#">award winners</a></li></ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer-container">
        <p id="footer-text"></p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
<!-- ... -->
```

I am not writing the popup in the HTML because it will be changed dynamically so I thought it would be easier to write it all in HTML. Any help would be appreciated thanks because I am stuck and without the popup, I can't implement the other features.

Comment: Hard to say as you did not include HTML, but I think you are querying for .popup before it exists.

Comment: @MalwareMoon I think you are probably right but do you think I can fix it? Because in my HTML I have almost nothing

Comment: Create that popup before you query it. I don't see why would you not make that popup into HTML and just set it to display:none in the first place. This is common a practice. But anyway, please include your HTML. because without it it's hard to trace the origin of the problem.

Comment: ok I will add my html

Comment: Well its still not working but I will keep trying

Answer (score 0):

There is sadly something wrong about every 4th line, so I have made a code sandbox where you can reverse engineer it from.

TL;DR

- element param does not exists
- Button that calls it does not exists
- details param does not exists
- .popup section does not exists
- document.body.appendChild will just stack them up on top of each other with each click
- renderMovies() does not exists

It is now appearing, but you will have to address all of the above for it to work as you probably desire.

[image: Edit rough-sky-b4cv7f]

Comment: thanks for the help but those elements are on another module... it's a big app... and those parts of the site are working ok just this module is giving me trouble